# xcode iphone problem for animating with timers

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, random

Hi everyone I'm French so excuse me for my poor English.
I'm making a game on the iphone with XCode and what I want to do is make something happen every ten seconds like a ball that jumps. Is there a tutorial for this sample code or example project for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to coding on the iPhone or coding in general try out [OpenFrameworks for the iPhone](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/iphone). They have great tutorials and have set up a lot of example projects for drawing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of example snippets in Apple's [Timer Programming Topics: Using Timers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html). Apple also provides a number of sample projects; the one you might be most interested in is [GKRocket](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GKRocket/), but you can [find a list here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/?q=nstimer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following:

```
- (void)animateBall
{
    // Animation for ball jumping.
    // This is just going to move it up and down but it's something to start

    float duration 1.0f;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    [imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 100.0f)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)run
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(animateBall) 
                                   userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:YES];
}
```

You will probably want an `UIImageView` containing a `UIImage` of a ball. You can modify the animation, or link to a secondary animation using UIView's `AnimationDidStopSelector`.

Comment: the problem is that I use a CADiplayLink 60fps per second and I think it's not possible to have to timers. what can I do

Comment: You may be able to detect when the animation finished using animationEnded:finished:context, then have that recall the animation. Add a bool flag to determine when to stop calling the animation.